# Cannot create an element in react component dynamically

Tags: reactjs

Im not able to create a React component dynamically.
I see blank page with no errors with below code.

1) Trying to create an element named  "PieChart"

2) Below are the Two errors im seeing in console.

```
1. Warning: <PieChart /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for    
   React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.

2. Warning: The tag <PieChart/> is unrecognized in this browser. If you
   meant to    render a React component, start its name with an
   uppercase letter.
```

3) Im Already using Pascal case "PieChart"

```
import PieChart from "../component/PieChart";
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    const GraphWidget = React.createElement("PieChart");
    return (
      <div>
        {GraphWidget}

      </div>
    )
  }


}


export default App;
```

Comment: Don't use quotes around `PieChart`, i.e. `const GraphWidget = React.createElement(PieChart);`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the [createElement documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement):

> Create and return a new React element of the given type. The type argument can be either a tag name string (such as 'div' or 'span'), a React component type (a class or a function), or a React fragment type.

You are trying to use *a React component type* therefore you cannot use a string, you need to use the class directly:

```
const GraphWidget = React.createElement(PieChart);
```

If your aim is to map strings to components, you can create simple mapping using a dictionary:

```
const components = {
    PieChart: PieChart
    ...
};

const GraphWidget = React.createElement(components['PieChart']);
```

Comment: Im getting "Piechart" from a Json Object  as  "type": "PieChart", any way i can do conversion before React.createElement(PieChart);

Comment: You can create a mapping from strings to components, I will update my answer with an example later.

Comment: I need to create a component bases on the Json response Dynamically. Do you suggest i need to create all the mappings of expected components  way before?  is there any way we can avoid this hard coding?

Comment: @Sumanthmadey That's exactly what I am saying. To be honest, the whole idea seems flawed. Passing a random react component through JSON is just now possible.

Comment: but how to add the key attribute to the child?
```createElement(FormBody,
              {
                pageConfig,
                key: section,
              }
            )``` it doesnt apply the key to <FormBody/>

Comment: Hey @Sumanthmadey you get any solution for load react component when it's come dynamically fron json objects?

Answer (score 0):

You should user `**PascalCase**` Naming conventions.

**For Example,**

```
class StudentGrades extends Component{

 // Your Stuff

}
```

Answer (score -4):

> the component you created should start with Capital latter and   using
>   this  within JSX also written with the same name

```
    class TodoItem extends React.Component {


      render(){

      return <TodoItem> 
     }
```

***this could be the one of the issue***